# Difference between two f.select option

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hopefully this is just a quicky....

I have a form to edit a product and each product belongs to a category.
In the form_for(@product) I can populate a select box for the categories in a couple of ways:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, Category.find(:all).collect{|c| [c.category, c.id]}, :prompt => "Pick a Category" %>
```

or:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.find(:all), :id, :category) %>
```

The first option remembers the category when editing the product, the second option doesn't.
Can anybody enlighten me as to why? Is there a way to use the options_from_collection_for_select in this scenario and have it remember the category upon editing?

Cheers,
Adam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Codeglot's answer should have been:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id , :name %>
```

(See [Rails: undefined method `map' for Ingredient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992587/rails-undefined-method-map-for-ingredient) for explanation)

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category, :id , :name %>
```

make sure you change `:name` to the field that you want displayed. It's probably `:name` or `:title`

Comment: I changed :name to :category but I get a "undefined method `map'" error using this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.find(:all), :id, :category, params[:category_id].to_i) %>
```

Comment: This doesn't remember what was selected when editing either. I have a category_id in my products table so there is a foreign key. And, as mentioned in my question <%= f.select :category_id, Category.find(:all).collect{|c| [c.category, c.id]}, :prompt => "Pick a Category" %> works perfectly. But can't get any sort of options_from_collection_for_select to work!!